# Grails - setting g:select value by clicking on img tag

Tags: javascript, grails

I'd like to know if there's a way to set `g:select` value by clicking on an img in a GSP page.

```
<img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'fiorentina.png')}" id = "Fiorentina">

<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: matchDayInstance, field: 'homeTeam1', 'error')} required">
    <label for="homeTeam1">
        <g:message code="matchDay.homeTeam1.label" default="Home Team1" />
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:select id="homeTeam1" name="homeTeam1.id" from="${com.baoole.domain.Team.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${matchDayInstance?.homeTeam1?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>
</div>
```

I've tried to write a little script to do this but without success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setOptionValue(event){
    $('#homeTeam1').val(${com.baoole.domain.Team.findByName("Fiorentina")});
}

var img = document.getElementById('Fiorentina');
img.addEventListener("click", setOptionValue);</script>
```

When I click on the image, it reset the select field.
I think the problem is `$('#homeTeam1').val(${com.baoole.domain.Team.findByName("Fiorentina")});`

Answer (score 0):

`id` and `'` are missing:

```
function setOptionValue(event){
  $('#homeTeam1').val( '${com.baoole.domain.Team.findByName("Fiorentina")?.id}' );
}
```

Comment: is there a way to have in the findByName query, not the particular team (like Fiorentina) but something like findByName("event.id") ??

Comment: you have to use an ajax request for that